# Rails Engine, change api_only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

i have monolithic business core, and multiple engines, like API and CMS.
Every engine is separate isolated apps with own router. They are not mixed together.
In core i have

```
config.api_only = true
config.generators.api_only = true
```

For API engine it is ok, but for CMS engine i need to re-enable fullstack Rails environment.

i tried many hooks defined in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-railtie-initializer
but nothing worked. I should add missing middleware but can't change `api_only` directive.

Is there nay way how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but did you revert `ApplicationController` to inherit from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ActionController::API`?